# react-typescript - How do I allow a specific component type to pass typescript check?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, components, react-typescript

I'm relatively new to typescript, although having a long experience with react (and prop-types).

I've encountered a problem with typing my component, if there's another component as a prop. I already have a `Button` component with a defined `type`.

Now the problem is, when I create a new component `ButtonGroup` having a `children` prop that only should allow `Button` components to be rendered. I'm comparing the `child`'s props to the `Button` type props - this means that I can pass there another component like `Input` if I don't break a button prop - like having `<Input id="input-id" />` is fine for typescript, but I don't want to allow that, because it's a different type of component.

I've successfully played with the `component.type.displayName`, but Typescript doesn't like this solution at all.

```
import { ReactElement, Children } from 'react'

type buttonVariantType = 'primary' | 'secondary' | undefined
type buttonProps = {
  id?: string
  variant?: buttonVariantType 
  children: ReactNode
  ...
}

const Button =({ children, id, variant = 'secondary' }) => {
  ...
  return <button ...>{children}</button>
}


interface buttonGroupProps {
  children: ReactElement<buttonProps>[]
  variant?: buttonVariantType 
}


const ButtonGroup = ({ children, variant }: buttonGroupProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Children.map(children, (child) => {
        // TS2339: Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'string | JSXElementConstructor<any>'
        if (child?.type.displayName !== 'Button') {
          console.log(child.type.displayName, 'not a button')
          throw Error('not a button') // ugly workaround, still unacceptable by typescript
        }
        return (
          <Button {...child?.props} variant={variant ?? child.props.variant}>
            {child.props.children}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now if I put another component as a `children` into ButtonGroup, the typescript is okay with that and I don't want that.

```
<ButtonGroup variant="danger">
  <Input id="123" /> 
  <Button variant="primary" id="primary">
    Primary button
  </Button>
  <Button variant="secondary" id="secondary">
    Secondary button
  </Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to make it compile time safe,reason for that is, when you declare any component with the jsx tags, the type that's created through that contains `any` for the values in the type. Let me give you an [example](https://tsplay.dev/mpQDxW) -

```ts
import * as React from "react";

type buttonProps = {
    id?: string;
    variant?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Button = ({ children, id, variant = 'secondary' }: buttonProps) => {
    return <button>{children}</button>
}

const div = () => <div></div>;
const input = () => <input></input>;
const Btn = () => <Button></Button>;

type Button = React.ReactElement<buttonProps, React.JSXElementConstructor<buttonProps>>;
type Div = ReturnType<typeof div>;
type Input = ReturnType<typeof input>;
type Btn = ReturnType<typeof Btn>;

type ExpandedButton = { [Property in keyof Button]: Button[Property] }
//   ^? type ExpandedButton = { type: React.JSXElementConstructor<buttonProps>; props: buttonProps; key: React.Key | null; }

type ExpandedDiv = { [Property in keyof Div]: Div[Property] };
//   ^? type ExpandedDiv = { type: any; props: any; key: React.Key | null; }

type ExpanedInput = { [Property in keyof Input]: Input[Property] };
//   ^? type ExpanedInput = { type: any; props: any; key: React.Key | null; 

type ExpandedBtn = { [Property in keyof Btn]: Btn[Property] };
//   ^? type ExpanedBtn = { type: any; props: any; key: React.Key | null;

type Assignable = (ExpandedButton extends (ExpandedDiv | ExpanedInput | ExpandedBtn | Div | Input | Btn) ? true : false) | ((ExpandedDiv | ExpanedInput | ExpandedBtn | Div | Input | Btn) extends ExpandedButton ? true : false);
//   ^? type Assignable = true
```

Which goes to show, any jsx element can be assigned to the other. As for a runtime error, you got it nearly right, the check that you should be making is to see if the component that's the child is actually the `Button` component through reference equality check, [like this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kind-chatelet-639zld) -

```ts
import { ReactElement, Children } from 'react'

type buttonVariantType = 'primary' | 'secondary' | undefined
type buttonProps = {
  id?: string
  variant?: buttonVariantType 
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

const Button =({ children, id, variant = 'secondary' }: buttonProps) => {
  return <button>{children}</button>
}


interface buttonGroupProps {
  children: ReactElement<buttonProps>[]
  variant?: buttonVariantType 
}


const ButtonGroup = ({ children, variant }: buttonGroupProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Children.map(children, (child) => {

        if (child?.type !== Button ) {
          throw Error('not a button')
        }

        return (
          <Button {...child?.props} variant={variant ?? child.props.variant}>
            {child.props.children}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Haven't really thought about assigning ... I'll stick to type checking using component.type as you suggested.